# Is it OK to mix liquid and powdered vitamins + supplements together?

Tags: nutrition, micronutrients, supplement, drug-interactions, liquids

Each week, I'm going to create liquid mixes of:

- liquid B12
- liquid fish oil
- liquid aloe vera extract
- powdered Rhodiola Rosea
- powdered L-Tyrosine

**Will these chemicals interfere with each other, or reduce bioavailability, if left dissolved together for a week or so?**

Thank you!

Comment: Fish oil can become rancid, it's usually mixed with vitamin E to prevent oxidation.